# ¿Es correcto decir "soy un hombre que me gusta lo mejor"?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

Nota: aprendí gracias a las respuestas que recordaba mal la canción, así que planteé mi pregunta original aquí, con mejor claridad: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "al que", "al cual" y "a quien"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/al-que-vs-al-cual-vs-a-quien).

---

Estaba tarareando hoy la canción del mariachi:

> Soy un hombre muy honrado que le gusta lo mejor.

De pronto me di cuenta de que en el primer verso hay un pequeño error y es lo que quisiera consultar con vosotros. ¿No os parece que más correcto sería así?

> Soy un hombre muy honrado **al que** le gusta lo mejor.

También me he topado con otras variantes: (soy) un hombre **al cual** (le gusta), (soy) un hombre **a quien** (le gusta)... ¿qué opináis? ¿Son todas correctas?

Comment: Interesante pregunta. Sin embargo, en todas las webs de letras de canciones que he visto en los resultados de Google, el verso dice: "Soy un hombre muy honrado, que me gusta lo mejor". No sé si ese pequeño cambio haría que replantearas la pregunta. ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]!

Comment: Muchas gracias, Carlos. Parece que recordaba mal la canción. No obstante, me gustaría recibir respuestas a la pregunta original, porque desde mucho llevo esta duda. Sé que se usan varias versiones, pero no estoy segura de las diferencias entre al que/al cual/a quien le gusta.

Comment: Pues si la letra original dice _soy un hombre que me gusta lo mejor_, entonces la letra original está equivocada. El referente es _hombre_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escucha este [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCmMDd8T5fg), que es la versión que yo conozco. Dice:

> Soy un hombre muy honrado
> **que** me gusta lo mejor
> a mujeres no me falta
> ni el dinero ni el amor.

Creo que este "que" es simplemente una conjunción copulativa, es decir un sinónimo de "y".

Esta acepción la recoge [el dicconario de la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UkbUarn), como número 6:

> **que**
>
> 6. conj. U. en vez de la copulativa y, pero denota cierto valor adversativo. Justicia pido, que no gracia. Suya es la culpa, que no mía.

---

¿O quizás la acepción 12?

> 12. conj. Precede a oraciones incidentales de sentido independiente. ¿Sabreisme decir, buen amigo, que buena ventura os dé Dios, dónde son por aquí los palacios de la sin par princesa doña Dulcinea del Toboso?

Al ser una canción, el significado de los versos, y la estructura gramatical no son prioritarios. Es más importante el ritmo, el número de sílabas, la rima... es ¿"a mujeres" o "las mujeres"? ¿"no me falta" o "no me faltan"?

Comment: No creo que en este caso se pueda entender como una conjunción copulativa. Para mi el artículo ni se puede suprimir y debería ser: al que le gusta. http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=que

Answer (score 2):

Tu idea original (es decir, que algo está mal o falta algo) es correcta. El verbo *gustar* requiere de una construcción gramatical donde al paciente (aquél que gusta de algo) se lo precede por la preposición *a*.  Puedes usar *al que*, *a quien* o *al cual* indistintamente en este caso.

Pero todo esto vale sólo para el registro formal (un libro, un informe, un discurso, una presentación laboral). En un registro más informal, por el contrario, usar algo más de *que* suena afectado. En una canción popular como la que citas el uso de *que* sin preposición es normal y esperable.

Por ejemplo, estas son frases que yo usaría hablando informalmente:

- Soy un tipo sencillo que no le gustan los platos raros.
- Hoy vino aquel hombre que le presté un libro hace tres meses.
- Esa actriz que le dieron el Oscar, ¿cómo se llamaba?

Incluso no es raro informalmente reemplazar otros pronombres relativos como *donde*:

- Nos alojamos en un hostel que había un grupo grande de alemanes.
- Nunca me acuerdo el lugar que guardo las cosas.

Por supuesto no recomendaría a nadie que esté aprendiendo español hablar de esta manera al principio, y yo tampoco usaría jamás construcciones de este tipo en un trabajo escrito.

Comment: ¡Hola pablodf76 y bienvenido a [spanish.se]! Gracias por todas estas interesantes respuestas que ya dejaste en apenas dos días. Supongo que ya has visto cómo funciona esto, pero siempre es interesante pasearse por el [tour] y por [answer] para completar la introducción.

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui, en eso estoy ahora. :)