# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "al que", "al cual" y "a quien"?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

Quisiera saber cuál es la diferencia entre:

> soy un hombre **al que** le gusta lo mejor
>
> soy un hombre **al cual** le gusta lo mejor
>
> soy un hombre **a quien** le gusta lo mejor

Pusé aquí ayer una pregunta similar pero la planteé mal:
[¿Es correcto decir "soy un hombre que me gusta lo mejor"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18574/soy-un-hombre-que-me-gusta-lo-mejor)
asi que al final la respuesta se dirigió a otro caso: "soy un hombre que me gusta lo mejor".
Como verán, la pregunta actual tiene otros matices.
Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 3):

Diría que las tres son equivalentes. Buscando en la RAE tenemos:

> **[el que](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UkbUarn)**
>
> 1. loc. pronom. Introduce una oración relativa con antecedente expreso. Usado tras preposición. *El hombre, con el que vive, dijo que se arrepentía, de lo que no me cabe duda.*
>
> ---
>
> **[el cual](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BRJtgeC)**
>
> 1. locs. pronoms. Introduce una oración de relativo con antecedente expreso. *A grandes voces llamó a Sancho, el cual, oyéndose llamar, dejó a los pastores.*
>
> ---
>
> **[quien](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UpfJQop)**
>
> 1. pron. relat. m. y f. El que, el cual o que. U. con antecedente referido a personas. Usado sin preposición solo encabeza oraciones explicativas. *El escritor invitado, quien trató ampliamente esa cuestión, es un especialista en la materia.*

Básicamente, puedes usar cualquiera (fíjate que en la definición de *quien* dice que significa *el que* o *el cual*). Hay, sin embargo, ligeras diferencias que se pueden ver si modificamos un poco la frase:

- *el que* debe ser usado con preposición: "al que". Si no, hay que quitar también el artículo: "soy un hombre, que gusta de lo mejor".
- *el cual* no necesita preposición, pero no puede prescindir del artículo: "soy un hombre, el cual gusta de lo mejor".
- *quien* nunca lleva artículo: "soy un hombre, quien gusta de lo mejor".

Comment: Una duda, usando la frase literal de @ringos staro "soy un hombre al que le gusta lo mejor" ¿Podría también eliminarse el artículo? "soy un hombre, que le gusta lo mejor". Es que me suena muy raro, no así tu ejemplo "que gusta de lo mejor" que suena bien

Comment: @blonfu suena muy raro, pero es posible si tenemos en cuenta [esta respuesta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18576/12637) a la pregunta paralela, que dice que "que" puede actuar como conjunción ("soy un hombre muy honrado y le gusta lo mejor"). Se podría interpretar como que la segunda parte de la frase es el hombre hablando de sí mismo en tercera persona. Raro, desde luego, pero posible.

Comment: Vale, pero entonces iría sin coma ¿no? y sí, la verdad que la tercera persona no cuadra mucho

Answer (score 2):

Yo diría que significan lo mismo, son intercambiables, según el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2VAvJgr6tD6bMa8swW):

> **1.2.2.2.** En oraciones especificativas, *que* puede llevar artículo con todas las preposiciones y en todas las funciones, y ha de llevarlo
>   necesariamente cuando el antecedente es de persona: *«Nunca engañaría
>   a un hombre al que amo»* (Ocampo Cornelia [Arg. 1988]); *«Por fin se
>   fue y, naturalmente, lo hizo con una señorita con la que estaba liado
>   desde hacía ya tiempo»* (RGodoy Mujer [Esp. 1990]). También aquí el
>   que es sustituible por *el cual* o por *quien*. Si el antecedente no
>   es de persona, el relativo con preposición puede construirse
>   opcionalmente sin artículo en los siguientes casos: (...)

Creo que ese es el caso de esta frase

Comment: ¡Bien buscado y bienvenido a [spanish.se]!

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida